# Displaying only unique values from array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, unique

First I check if the current value is part of the array of already displayed values. If it's not, I display it. I still get duplicate values and I don't know why.. Here's my code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $displayed = array();
    if (!(in_array($row['Brand'],$displayed)))
    {
        array_push($displayed,$row['Brand']);
        echo '<li>';
        echo $row['Brand'];
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reinitializing `$displayed = array();` on every iteration of the `while` loop and essentially clearing any data in it. Move it outside, before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_unique($array)`  to remove every repeated value easily .

[**Refrence**](https://www.php.net/function.array-unique)

Answer (score 0):

You are re-initializing the array on each iteration, so you are effectively checking if `$row['Brand']` exists in an empty array. It doesn't and hence `in_array` returns false. Move the array declaration outside the loop.

```
$displayed = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    # code ...
}
```

<sub>Usual disclaimer: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and are soon to be removed. Please switch to MySQLi or PDO instead.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
$displayed = array(); //move here 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if (!(in_array($row['Brand'],$displayed)))
    {
        array_push($displayed,$row['Brand']);
        echo '<li>';
        echo $row['Brand'];
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
```